# Getting Blank Screen Using HTML5 video player

Tags: html, video, mp4

I am trying to display 10-20 short clips on my website. The code below is the code I use to display the video. It works perfectly if I only need to display 1-4 videos. But if I tried to display 10-20 videos simultaneously, some of these videos get a black screen instead. I tried to test this, on different browsers. Only Firefox is capable of displaying them perfectly without a problem.

```
<video controls="controls" class="gif_vid" width="auto" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="" poster="trans.gif"><source src="http://zippy.gfycat.com/ImprobableCornyFunnelweaverspider.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="http://zippy.gfycat.com/ImprobableCornyFunnelweaverspider.mp4" type="video/webm"></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems a little odd, I just tried copy pasting your code 20 times and it ran without any issues. In order to make sure they are not loading open up the developer console and check the network status. It should give you a little more information regarding why they dont show or why it takes so long.

Comment: Try different url per each video

Comment: Could you post the links you are trying to use, just to make sure we are on the same page, thx